# Get all key based value from a JSON array Object in PHP

Tags: php, json

i am looking to get `invoices` from the below JSON in an seperate array.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Demo Name",
      "email":"info@demo.com",
      "mobile":"881730344",
      "mobilealt":"78693446777",
      "gender":"male",
      "address":"102a sdf",
      "description":"Super admin role and super admin permissions",
      "profileimage":"profileimage\/team1.jpg",
      "status":"active",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":"2016-06-29 17:08:24",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "under_id":0,
      "assign_at":"2016-05-11 10:41:50",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "id":17,
            "under_id":1,
            "name":"Some Name",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "id":35,
                  "under_id":17,
                  "name":"test sub user ",
                  "children":[  

                  ],
                  "invoices":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "id":36,
                  "under_id":17,
                  "name":"Harsh",
                  "children":[  

                  ],
                  "invoices":[  

                  ]
               }
            ],
            "invoices":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":18,
            "under_id":1,
            "name":"Demo Demo Sname",
            "children":[  

            ],
            "invoices":[  
               {  
                  "order_id":31,
                  "sum":161500,
                  "month":"May",
                  "user_id":18
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":20,
            "under_id":1,
            "name":"Divya",
            "children":[  

            ],
            "invoices":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":25,
            "under_id":1,
            "name":"Dhiraj",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "id":19,
                  "under_id":25,
                  "name":"New user",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "id":33,
                        "under_id":19,
                        "name":"Demo Sub Sub user",
                        "children":[  

                        ],
                        "invoices":[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "invoices":[  
                     {  
                        "order_id":32,
                        "sum":40000,
                        "month":"July",
                        "user_id":19
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "invoices":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am thinking of recursive loop. But i tried the below method, which do not seems to be working.

```
public function take_invoices($array){
      static $arrinvoices = [];
      foreach($array as $item){
          if(count($item->invoice) > 0){
            dd($item->invoice);              //------------->Laravel function to die and dump. its always empty
              $arrinvoices[] = $item->invoice;
          }
          if(count($item->children) > 0){
            $this->take_invoices($item->children);
          }
      }

    return $arrinvoices;
  }
```

Thank you! (in advance!)

Comment: there are many empty `"invoices"`, should they be omitted?

Comment: you have several invoices... Which one you need??

Comment: Yes, i am trying to skip the empty once.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_match_all` and `preg_replace` functions:

```
// $json_data - is your initial json string
// the next step takes all non-empty 'invoices'
preg_match_all("/\"invoices\":\[([^]]+)\]/", preg_replace("/\f|\v|\h|\t|\s+/", "", $json_data), $matches);
$invoices = [];
if (!empty($matches) && isset($matches[1])) {
    $invoices = json_decode("[" . implode(",", $matches[1]) . "]", true);
}

print_r($invoices);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 31
            [sum] => 161500
            [month] => May
            [user_id] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 32
            [sum] => 40000
            [month] => July
            [user_id] => 19
        )
)
```

Comment: I am getting the invoices, but now when i am trying to get the `children` then its not displaying children.

Comment: @user3201500, you have asked about *to get invoices*. As `invoices` are independent items in that structure, but `children` items are items with unknown nested levels

Comment: Yes actually, i am trying to create a global function to get any value from this json object. So it can easily be fetched.

Comment: and how should look the expected result when searched for `children`?

Comment: Each children will come as in array, **same as `invoices`**.

Comment: it can not be same as invoices, cause `children` has nested levels. Should it extract only the "deepest" `children`(on the deepest level)?